# Why doesn't callback work for sorting?

Tags: php, laravel

I have method in my ArticlesController for sorting articles depending on request GET parameters:

```
protected static function sortArticles(Collection $articles, string $sort_by, string $order): Collection
    {
        $sortBy = function ($by, $order) use ($articles) {
            if ($order === 'asc') {
                $method = 'sortBy';
            } elseif ($order === 'desc') {
                $method = 'sortByDesc';
            }

            return call_user_func([$articles, $method], [$by]);

        };


        switch ($sort_by) {
            case 'title':
                return $sortBy('title', $order);
                break;
            case 'views':
                return $sortBy('views_count', $order);
                break;
            case 'comments':
                return $sortBy(function ($article) { // This is my callback for sorting and it doesn't work as expected
                    return count($article->comments);
                }, $order);
                break;
            case 'date':
                return $sortBy('created_at', $order);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Everything works ok, but when sort_by=comments (3rd case in Switch), it just doesn't work:

> (1/1) ErrorException Object of class Closure could not be converted to
>   string

Don't know why, the sortByDesc method called by call_user_func on Collection instance doesn't accept Closure as it's argument and tries to convert it to string.
If I directly call sortBy or sortByDesc on Collection, everything works ok:

```
    case 'comments':
    return $articles->sortBy(function ($article) { // Gives no errors
        return count($article->comments);
    });
    break;
```

Comment: Can't you just use `count($article->comments)` as the argument instead of the closure?

Comment: @NathanHeffley So what will it count in that context? Argument for sortBy() must be a string containing element's property name or Closure returning value for each Collection element. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortby

Comment: You want to sort by the number of comments, not by the comments themselves... you are returning a count where call_user_func expect $by which is a field name... thus the string problem...

Comment: @Serge can you look into the documentation? The sortBy method accepts callback!

Answer (score 1):

When fetching your model... add the withCount('comments') function... as:

```
$articles = App\Article::with('comments')->withCount('comments')->get();
```

Then you can simply use comment_count in your sort...

```
case 'comments':
    return $sortBy('comments_count', $order);
    break;
```

This will add a count attribute to your model that contains the count of comments. The convention is that it will store the count in the attribute with the name of the relationship followed by _count... In your case $article->comments_count ...

Hope this works for you...

Comment: Nice solution, but don't you know why does my code give error?

Comment: Well for one, call_user_func does not pass it's params by reference... so I am thinking that is what is getting you here... did you try call_user_func_array? I believe that might work...